# Change doctrine connection on form class and Doctrine Fixtures

Tags: forms, doctrine-orm, symfony

I have some form, and one column have `Entity` type, but this entity have another connection.

In action i can `$em->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager('name')`

How to change connection in form class?

Maybe can possibly change connection in entity class.
Like this

```
orm:
    default_entity_manager: default
    entity_managers:
        owner:
            connection: owner
            mappings:
                RealestateCoreBundle:
                    Entity: MyEntity
```

UPDATED:

I found answer here :)

http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/forms/types/entity.html#em

But how i can change connection in data fixtures class?

I try:

```
<?php

namespace Realestate\CoreBundle\DataFixtures\ORM;

use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\FixtureInterface;
use Realestate\CoreBundle\Entity\Owner;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

class OwnerFixtures implements FixtureInterface, ContainerAwareInterface
{

    private $container;

    public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container = null)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function load($manager)
    {
        $this->container->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager('owner');

        for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) {
            $owner = new Owner();
            $owner->setName('name-' . $i);
            $owner->setTelephone(mt_rand(100000, 999999));
            $manager->persist($owner);
        }

        $manager->flush();
    }

}
```

but didnt work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When loading fixtures you can use the flag when executing the console command to change the entity manager:

[Executing Fixtures](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html#executing-fixtures)

```
php app/console doctrine:fixtures:load --em=manager_name
```

Alternatively you could check out this section in the same docs:

[Using the container in fixtures](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html#using-the-container-in-the-fixtures)

If your fixture class has access to the container then you could load any entity manager you wish.

```
$container->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager('manager_name');
```

Comment: its 

`$container->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager('manager_name');` 

doest work

Comment: True... it should have been more like `$this->container->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager('manager_name');` as long as your fixture is container aware as described in the link above. That's the important bit if you wish to do it this way, your fixture must implement `ContainerAwareInterface`. Passing the manager's name on the command line is likely an easier method though.

Comment: Ah yes, because you still need to assign the return to manager and use it... `$manager = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager('owner');` or you can execute normal fixtures with `php app/console doctrine:fixtures:load --em=owner`

Answer (score 0):

If your fixture has access to container, with your actual config in config.yml : 

    `orm:
    default_entity_manager: default`enter code here
    `entity_managers:
        owner:
            connection: owner
            mappings:
                RealestateCoreBundle:
                    Entity: MyEntity`

you can call the entity manager like that :

`$manager = $this->container->get('doctrine.orm.owner_entity_manager');`